# Scroll bar for a select tag(Multiple select) without using div (not working in firefox)

Tags: html, css

```css
.selector select[multiple="multiple"] {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  max-width: 368px !important;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 368px !important;
}
```

```html
<select id="id_included_packages_from" class="filtered" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1" title="Internet">Internet Everywhere</option>
  <option value="2" title="Internet 20MB">Internet 20MB/Day</option>
  <option value="3" title="Trnet Plus">Early internet days, fetching the file.......................................................TTTTT.</option>
</select>
```

Scroll is being enabled in google chrome but not in Firefox. can horizontal scroll bar be kept without adding div tag

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you might speak of a horizontal scrollbar. The answer is: 
You can not do this without the `div` trick cross Browser.

But there is nothing bad about using a div for that. Why do you want to avoid it? Maybe we can help you on that.

---

old answer: You can have a ScrollBar like this:

```css
.filtered {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<select id="id_included_packages_from" class="filtered" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1" title="Internet">Internet Everywhere</option>
  <option value="2" title="Internet 20MB">Internet 20MB/Day</option>
  <option value="2" title="Internet 20MB">Internet 20MB/Day</option>
  <option value="2" title="Internet 20MB">Internet 20MB/Day</option>
  <option value="3" title="Trnet Plus">Early internet days, fetching the file.......................................................TTTTT.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: there are couple of <div> tags already on top of select tag. If I am adding scroll bar to inner div uppermost div length is restricting inner div scroll. I will update the image in a bit